# Unhandled Exception: FormatException

Tags: flutter

I am using MVVM and I try to catch error in my view but It crash in the viewmodel with 'Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Not implemented'

Main app:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
...
  runApp(
....
}
```

View

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    viewModel = Provider.of<TodoViewModel>(context, listen: false);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      try {
        viewModel.getTodos();
      } on FormatException catch (e) {
        DialogMessage.showErrorMessage(context, e.toString());
      }
    });
  }
```

ViewModel

```
  Future<void> getTodos() async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    try {
      throw const FormatException('Not implemented');
      //_todos = await todoRepository.getTodos();
    } on FormatException catch (e) {
      throw e; // Crash here and don't send error to view
    } finally {
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: This line `throw const FormatException('Not implemented');` throw `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Not implemented`. Remove it and add implementation you want.

Answer (score 0):

you are intentionally throwing a `FormatException` in your `getTodos` method,

try this:

```dart
 Future<void> getTodos() async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    try {
      //_todos = await todoRepository.getTodos();
    } on FormatException catch (e) {
      throw e; // Crash here and don't send error to view
    } finally {
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it's because it is try to to have the exception forwarded  and handle by the view with a message.

Comment: in try the first statement is throw which will throw Exception and all other statements after this will not run and the control will go to catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Need to do async/await on the futur method.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
  try {
    await viewModel.getTodos();
  } on FormatException catch (e) {
    DialogMessage.showErrorMessage(context, e.toString());
  }
});
```